# Atom says I need to install Python through Microsoft Store but I have Python Installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, atom-editor

PyCharm was being stupid so I decided to use Atom. Before, I had stupidly downloaded Python from the official website and the Microsoft store, so it caused errors on PyCharm which meant I had to use Atom.

However, recently I managed to fix that issue by uninstalling Python from the Microsoft store and installing the latest version of Python with the PATH properly configured, but it only fixed PyCharm but not Atom.

However, whenever I try to run a script on Atom, I get this error message:
`Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640`

I have Python installed from the website but not the MS store. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/a/1442909/291007) help? Or maybe [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/after-windows-update-atom-says-python-isnt-installed/70115/7) is a better way

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter whether you download Python from the Microsoft Store or from python.org. What matters is that Python is installed on your system and that any application using that version of the interpreter can access it. Typically, this means that you have any entry on your PATH environment variable to the directory of your Python interpreter.

From what you've described, it sounds like you may have had more than one version on your system at the same time, and then you removed one and made some modifications to your PATH variable. I would confirm that your PATH variable is correct and that you can run the Python interpreter from a Command Prompt window by invoking it directly. If you can do that, then Atom ought to be able to find your Python interpreter. If it cannot, then I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling Atom rather than uninstalling and reinstalling Python.

I would like to help more, but would need more info about your system to provide a more specific steps.

Comment: I just ended up using PyCharm instead, but I'd like Atom as a backup. Also, only `py --version` works and `python --version` or `python3 --version` doesn't work.

Comment: That means that python's directory isn't in your PATH. Within your PyCharm, you should be able to run an interpreter. Run `import sys; sys.path` and that will tell you where python in installed. You can then add that directory to your path.